# Vue: prevent access to view if props not set

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm developing a game in Vue which has 2 views: a 'setup' and a 'play'. The parameters you set in the former get passed as props in the latter, and the game begins with those parameters.

But there is nothing stopping from a user from directly accessing `.../#/play`, thereby bypassing the setting of the required props. I get around this by setting sensible defaults...

```
props: {
  prop: { default: 'sensible default' },
  // ...
},
```

... but I'm wondering how to restrict access to that view entirely if the user did not reach it via `.../#/setup`. I'm aware of `required: true` and navigation guards, but not sure how to go about utilising either/both in this case, or if they're even the best option.

Is there an easy way to redirect if `.../#/play` is accessed directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `beforeEnter` [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks):

```js
routes: [
  {
    path: '/setup',
    name: 'setup',
    component: Setup
  },
  {
    path: '/play',
    name: 'play',
    component: Play,
    props: true, // <-- converting params to props
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      if (to.params.myprop) {
        next(); // <-- everything good, proceed
      } else {
        next({ name: 'setup' }); // <-- redirect to setup
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This is checking that a certain param exists before allowing navigation to the `play` route, otherwise it redirects back to `setup`.

Comment: Works perfectly but if I remove from param from beforeEnter it does not redirect, do you know why?

Comment: @Lepy You can't do that.  If you remove the `from` param, then `next` will be the 2nd param and the value meant for `from` will be passed to `next` instead.

Comment: thanks, I didn't knew that the parameter order matters so much!

Comment: @Lepy No problem.  Yeah, it's because Vue calls your `beforeEnter` function and passes 3 params to it, always in that order.